# How to add "and" and "or" filters at the same time in a druid query?

Tags: druid

I am trying to write a druid query (json file) which is "and" and "or" filters at the same time. I tried this:

```
{
  "queryType": "select",
  "dataSource": "timeseries_db",
  "intervals": ["2020-09-08T17:00:00\/2020-09-08T17:30:00"],
  "pagingSpec":{ "threshold":100},
  "filter": {
    "type": "and",
    "fields": [
      {
        "type": "selector",
        "dimension": "orgid",
        "value": "864e1875-ea80-455b-a835-f75bed0df2a7"
      },
      "filter": {
        "type": "or",
        "fields": [
         {
           "type": "selector",
           "dimension": "host_name",
           "value": "testname.82fae43ca"
         },
         {
           "type": "selector",
           "dimension": "host_name",
           "value": "testname.09db12d4a"
         }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "granularity": "all"
}
```

I want to get the records whose org id is 864e1875-ea80-455b-a835-f75bed0df2a7 and whose host name is testname.82fae43ca or testname.09db12d4a

When I run this query, it throws error saying that "type" is missing. But I have included "type". Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the extra `"filter"` inside the `and` filter. Try this:

```
{
  "queryType": "select",
  "dataSource": "timeseries_db",
  "intervals": ["2020-09-08T17:00:00\/2020-09-08T17:30:00"],
  "pagingSpec":{ "threshold":100},
  "filter": {
    "type": "and",
    "fields": [
      {
        "type": "selector",
        "dimension": "orgid",
        "value": "864e1875-ea80-455b-a835-f75bed0df2a7"
      },
      {
        "type": "or",
        "fields": [
         {
           "type": "selector",
           "dimension": "host_name",
           "value": "testname.82fae43ca"
         },
         {
           "type": "selector",
           "dimension": "host_name",
           "value": "testname.09db12d4a"
         }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "granularity": "all"
}
```

---

Another way to do this is to use an `in` filter instead of two `selector` filters inside an `or`:

```
{
  "queryType": "select",
  "dataSource": "timeseries_db",
  "intervals": ["2020-09-08T17:00:00\/2020-09-08T17:30:00"],
  "pagingSpec":{ "threshold":100},
  "filter": {
    "type": "and",
    "fields": [
      {
        "type": "selector",
        "dimension": "orgid",
        "value": "864e1875-ea80-455b-a835-f75bed0df2a7"
      },
      {
        "type": "in",
        "dimension": "host_name",
        "values": ["testname.82fae43ca", "testname.09db12d4a"]
      }
    ]
  },
  "granularity": "all"
}
```